# How to scale an InDesign document through script?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have an .indd document that I am resizing with the script below, and then exporting as an image. When I increase the dimensions extra blank spaces are added, and when I reduce the dimensions the image gets cropped. How can I scale the document, instead of cropping or adding extra space?

Javascript so far:

```
var myDocument = app.open(File("filename.indd"));

var myPages = myDocument.pages;

myPages.item(0).resize(CoordinateSpaces.PAGE_COORDINATES,AnchorPoint.CENTER_ANCHOR,
ResizeMethods.MULTIPLYING_CURRENT_DIMENSIONS_BY,[2,2],true);

var myPDFExportPreset = app.pdfExportPresets.item("[Press Quality]");

myDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, File(Folder.desktop + "/anchor3.jpg"),   myPDFExportPreset);
```

Comment: what script language? IF IT IS IN INDESIGN, I think it might be better suited of SuperUser

Comment: thanks for your reply, javascript is the script language.... and what is SuperUser can you explain please

Comment: SuperUser is SO but not for programming BUT for power users of software. So it deals a lot with those applications... and this seems to me to be more of a power user thingy :)

Comment: but I might be wrong and I don't know indesign that well

Comment: k thanks for comments...

Comment: It *is* a programming problem. The language is, more precisely, ExtendScript.

Comment: Please add your *InDesign version* -- I assume this is for CS6 or CC, since you appear to try to resize a **page**. (Which, incidentally, explains why the margins change, instead of 'everything on the page'.)

Comment: thanks ya its ExtendScript but i think it uses two script javascript and vbscript and i am using javascript with CS6 server 64 bit....

Comment: http://www.directlinkupload.com/uploads/182.71.87.20/blankspaces.jpg http://www.directlinkupload.com/uploads/182.71.87.20/cropped.jpg       Here are the links of two images first one i have enlarged which blank spaces are being added, second one i have decreased the dimensions which is cropped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code is resizing the page itself, but none of the items on the page. You'll also need to scale the items on the page. In other words, you want the script equivalent of running these commands from the UI: (1) Select all, (2) Object > Transform > Scale.

To do that in a script, you need to group all the objects on a page and then scale the group. [This script](http://www.appliness.com/automatic-rescale-with-indesign/) shows an example of doing that.

Note that you want to scale, not resize, the page elements. If you resize a text frame, the frame gets bigger but the text inside it doesn't. This will change your line breaks, etc. If you scale the text frame, the text gets proportionally bigger and the lines still break in the same place.

Comment: thanks for your reply  i am using the same approach of resizing all items of page but with different scripts...  thanks again